# Automapper, property exists in source and destination, fill destination with other value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm working in an existing system where foreignKeys fields do not have 'Id' in them.

```
public class person
{
   public int Country {get;set;}      // = ForeignKey
   public string Country1 {get;set;}  // = countryName
}

public class personDto
{
   public string Country {get;set;}  // should get the CountryName (=Country1 property in Person)
}
```

In the datalayer Country1 is automatically filled via Join with the name of the country.

Now I want automapper to fill personDto.Country with person.Country1 so I create this mapping.

```
CreateMap<person, personDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Country1))
```

But upon mapping the result is

```
{
  Country: "1"
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to correctly solve this?

I would like for automapper to:

- Ignore property Country from the source
- Fill property Dto.Country with Source.Country1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Hi @Jurjen, it should be `opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Country1 )`. Could you please share the code how do you map the model? It works well in my project.

Comment: Hi @Rena, thanks you for responding. I couldn't share the actual example for privacy reasons so I typed this example directly into the message. I have now created the actual example and it does work as expected! just strange that in my actual scenario this doesn't seem to work...  I'm going to do some checking and get back to you

Comment: Hi Rena, it would seem my code is at fault here, it turns out that Country1 also contains "1"... so that would explain it... sorry for the inconvenience.